# Retrieving entire DropDownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

How can i recover all my DropDownList options? I've tried a lot of different things, but none of them worked. I don't want just the selected value, but the entire options, with it's `text` and `value`.

I tried to use `$('form').serialize()` and while it recover complex objects through model binding to my controller, the entire dropdownlist is lost, only it's selected value returns.

I tried even generating a json object with following structure (unsuccessfully):

```
var list = [
{
"MyDropDownList":
{ "option": {"Text": "Some text", "Value": "Some value"} },
{ "option": {"Text": "Ohter text", "Value": "Other value"} } 
}
];
```

I'm really considering to create a nested object to emulate a dropdownlist, instead of using the `List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: How was the Dropdown generated? if it is bound to a model property (or even view bag property) wouldn't it be enough to send that property back to the controller? if I understood correctly that by recover you meant send back to a controller.

Comment: @JTMon It is bound to a ViewModel property, called `MyList` which is `List<SelectListItem>`. And you're correct, i meant send it back to my controller.

Comment: I am not sure how you are calling your controller, but have you tried includind the MyList property as part of the call and have the controller accept a parameter named MyList of type List<SelectListItem>, the framework should do the mapping for you.